# Jersey endpoint not found

Tags: java, spring, jersey

I have two endpoints in my Java Jersey web service:

- {host}/{accountNo}
- {host}/{accountNo}/service

Due to some problem with other systems i need to add a regex to validate the accountNo, so i only to enter both endpoints if the accountNo is aplhanumeric.

This was my solution:

- @Path("/{accNo : [a-zA-Z0-9]*$}") for the first endpoint
- @Path("/{accNo : [a-zA-Z0-9]*$}/service") for the second enpoint

The first endpoint is working fine and it validates everything that i wanted
However , every time i try to call endpoint 2 it returns not found.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work:

```
@Path("/{accNo: [a-zA-Z0-9]*}/service")
```

Just remove `$` that means *end of line*.